# Searching for a word and not a string?

Tags: string, vb.net, contains, cpu-word

I want to check a file for a particular word the way I have found posted on various forums is to use the following code...

```
Dim content = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath)
If content.Contains("stringToSearch") Then
    'Do your stuff
End If
```

Which is okay until you discover that it will search and match compound words and the likes. For instance If I search for the string `light` in a file and it's not there but instead the word `lightning` is, it will still register as having found a match... Is there a way to find and exact word using VB.net?

Comment: You might find the word boundary [anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions) `\b` in a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) to be useful for that.

Comment: If i understand correctly that would be like the following? If content.Contains("\bstringToSearch\b") Then

Comment: More like `If Regex.Match(Regex.Match(stringToSearch, "\bstringToSearch\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` (that last part is just a suggestion)

Comment: could you not then just append a space to each end of the user's search word to make it a word only search? `...content.contains(" " & stringtosearch & " ")`

Comment: @CharlesMay Consider if that would work if the sought word was the first one in the file, or at the end of a sentence and so followed by a full stop.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Should have given more thought to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Andrew Morton, Regex makes this kind of thing very easy.  For instance, if you made a function like this:

```
Public Function ContainsWord(input As String, word As String) As Boolean
    Return Regex.IsMatch(input, $"\b{word}\b")
End Function
```

You could use it like this:

```
Dim content = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath)
If ContainsWord(content, "stringToSearch") Then
    'Do your stuff
End If
```

If you wanted to, you could even make it an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-write-an-extension-method) on the `String` type, by putting it in a Module and adding the `ExtensionAttribute`, like this:

```
<Extension>
Private Function ContainsWord(input As String, word As String) As Boolean
    Return Regex.IsMatch(input, $"\b{word}\b")
End Function
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
Dim content = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath)
If content.ContainsWord("stringToSearch") Then
    'Do your stuff
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, using [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches), which allows to search for a collection of words and returns a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer())`.

The Dictionary **`Key`** represent the matched word, the **`Value`**, as an Array of Integers, all the positions inside the File where the word was found.

The extension method requires 2 parameters:
- the path of the file to search
- a boolean value, used to specify whether the search should be case sensitive.

Proposed as an extension method of `IEnumerable(Of String)`:

```
Dim fileName As String = "[File Path]"
Dim searchWords As String() = {"light", "lighting", "clip", "clipper", "somethingelse"}
Dim result = searchWords.FindWords(fileName, False)
```

Print a result of the matches found:

```
result.ToList().ForEach(
    Sub(w)
        Console.WriteLine($"Word: {w.Key} Positions: {String.Join(", ", w.Value)}")
    End Sub)
```

Extension method:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module modIEnumerableExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function FindWords(words As IEnumerable(Of String),
                              fileName As String,
                              caseSentive As Boolean) As Dictionary(Of String, Integer())
        Dim pattern As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        pattern.Append(String.Concat(words.Select(Function(w) $"\b{w}\b|")))

        Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Compiled Or
            If(caseSentive, RegexOptions.Multiline, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)

        Dim regx As New Regex(pattern.ToString().TrimEnd("|"c), options)
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = regx.Matches(File.ReadAllText(fileName))

        Dim groups = matches.OfType(Of Match).
            GroupBy(Function(g) g.Value).
            ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.Select(Function(m) m.Index).ToArray())
        Return groups
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score -1):

The shortest and fastest way to do this is using [ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2) with LINQ queries, specialy when you are working with a large files.

```
Dim myword As String = "Book"
Dim reg = New Regex("\b" & myword & "\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim res = From line In File.ReadLines(largeFileName)
                  Where reg.IsMatch(line)
```

If your file containts "Book", "Books", "Book." and "Book," the results will be:

```
Book
Book,
Book.
```

And you can working with results as following

```
TextBox1.Text = resLines.Count
```

Or

```
TextBox1.Text = resLines(0)
```

**Edited to make it consering "." and "," etc.**

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ LINQ makes it shortest way and ReadLines makes it the fastest way specialy with large files as I mentioned, please read the ReadLines's and LINQ's documentation before downvote!

Comment: **"By using query syntax, you can perform filtering, ordering, and grouping operations on data sources with a **minimum** of code."**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

**"Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient."**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2

`I understand` I hope!

Comment: `see if a word exist` exists where? in a file? so how could you search for a word in a file without reading every single word in this file? the answer is you COULDN'T, so you need to do read all lines in the file but in an efficient way and that's exactly why we do using ReadLines.

Comment: And now you have deleted all your comments here :)

Comment: Its irrelevant and the discussion was long. The answer by Steven is best in this situation.

Comment: Yeah! my code can search 100mb text file and get the results in just 2 seconds, if you try using ReadAllText you need 2 hours to get the contents (LOL) and of course leaks memory and you may get "out of memory exception".